# Correct format of 32-bit pyodbc Access DB connection string?

Tags: python, regex, ms-access, pyodbc

I have a 32-bit program which uses pyodbc to interact with an Access DB.  It gives me the following error:

"('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name. ..."

Below is the code which causes the error.

```
    conn_str = (r'DRIVER={'+myDriver+'};'
                 r'DBQ=\\\\ABC-ENTFS-050\\Storage\\FileFolder\\Files Here\\One More\\Last One\\A Random DB.accdb;'
                 r'ReadOnly=0')
```

Originally, I was using single backslashes because a 64-bit version of the program works with them.  However, using single backslashes with the 32-bit version I received a file path error ("is not a valid path").

After some research, I switched from single to double backslashes because of regular expression rules.  It was then I started receiving the "Not a valid file name" error.

Would anybody please help me to better understand the proper format to use a 32 bit OBDC driver with pyodbc?  Is it only the r' that's causing the problem? Why would the 64-bit version not need the escape character? Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to double-up backslashes in a raw string literal; that's the whole point of them. And 32-bit vs. 64-bit makes no difference *per se*. There must be something else going on. (Different versions of Python, perhaps?)

Comment: Thanks Gord.  Different versions of python is likely the case then.  The 32-bit installation is 3.7.7 and 64-bit 3.7.6..  
To get it working, I put everything on one line and removed the r' prefix.  I know it doesn't help my understanding of correct regex usage, so it's definitely a topic I need to study more.  Thanks again.